# How to use alloca to allocate C function pointers?

Tags: c, function-pointers, alloca

C is a mystery all the time!

I am implementing a work-crew thread execution model in which I am trying to use alloca as a faster memory allocation option. I have a strange segmentation fault while trying to execute code via function pointers stored on the stack using alloca.

Here's a tooth-pick code which results in a similar segmentation fault:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef void* (*foo)(void*);

typedef struct task
{
    foo f;
} task;

void *blah(void* v)
{
    printf("addr:%p\n", &v);
    return v;
}

int main()
{
    void *queue[10]; 

    task *t = (task*) alloca (sizeof(task));
    // No null check, excuse me!
    t->f = blah;

    queue[0] = (void*)t;
    char string[10] = "Bingo!";
    char *c = &string[0];

    task *tnew = (task*)&queue[0];
    tnew->f((void*)c);

    return 0; 
}
```

When I execute the above code I get a segmentation fault at the tnew->f() line.
GDB backtrace did not help me much.

Kindly explain the error in the above code.. I am using alloca for the first time.

Thank you very much!

Comment: I don't think alloca is the issue here given that replacing with `malloc` results in the same error.

Comment: Why do you think you need go use `alloca` to allocate space for a struct. You can just create an object on the stack, `task T; task* t = &T;` would do it.

Comment: Don't use `alloca` if you don't have to. It is non-standard and non-portable and its behavior of reserving stack memory regardless of scope is a source of many surprises. Modern C, aka C99, has variable length arrays (VLA) that are designed to replace it. But as Bo says, never use such a thing to create just one variable on the stack. There is really no point in this.

Comment: I think I have not writen the above test code properly. Thank you for solving the issue with the test code and additional info on alloca. In my opinion, the issue I have with my work-crew threads application (not the above test code) deals with alloca and memory fences. I will post a better tooth-pick test code soon.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change this line:

```
task* tnew = (task*)&queue[0];
```

to

```
task* tnew = (task*)queue[0];
```

Because `queue[0]` is already a pointer; you don't need to take the address of it.  You have the same issue inside `blah`.  Your `printf` won't crash, but it will print out the address of the pointer, not the value of the pointer, which probably isn't what you want.

Comment: Thank you very much! You are absolutely right. That hit the spot. :-)

Comment: If you want the compiler to spot this kind of problem for you, take all the casts out and give 'queue' the correct type rather than void *[].

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you might also want to pass the parameter "v"?

```
t->f = blah; // BAD

t->f = blah (SOMETHING); // Better...
```